# In Windows 10, how to change username?

Tags: windows-10, window, username

In Windows 10, how to change username for the following seemingly broken state?

I changed my user name, say from xxx to xxxy in my Windows 10 computer following the instruction in [https://www.groovypost.com/howto/change-account-name-windows-10/#:~:text=Press%20Windows%20key%20%2B%20R%2C%20type,again%20to%20confirm%20the%20change](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/change-account-name-windows-10/#:%7E:text=Press%20Windows%20key%20%2B%20R%2C%20type,again%20to%20confirm%20the%20change). But after installing Tencent QQ, a popular messenger app in China and Asia, when it starts, it complains that it could not access

```
C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Documents\Tencent Files\
```

But my new username is xxxy! And then the program could NOT be started. Any suggestion how I might be able to fix this?

Comment: The user profile directory never changes because programs may have stored absolute file names to files inside the profile directory in registry or custom config files. Therefore Windows never changes the path of the user profile dir if you rename the user. If the program does not start this is a bug which should be corrected by the program developer.

Comment: I'm not following. Are you saying Tencent QQ stored the old user name 'xxx' somewhere and therefore caused the issue?

Comment: That is one possible reason. What is actual path of the folder?